# How to inherit from the Grids class in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Here's my class that I inherit from the TStringGrid class. I want to create a grid that will be populated with data from a database. But now this is only just a simple class stub:

```
unit clsTCustomStringGrid;

interface

    uses Grids, Dialogs;

    type
        TCustomStringGrid = class (TStringGrid)
            public
                procedure SayHello ();
        end;

implementation

    procedure TCustomStringGrid.SayHello ();
    begin
        ShowMessage('Hello World!');
        // procedure body
    end;

end.
```

This is what I have in the main form:

```
uses ...
     ...
    TCustomStringGrid; // here is where the compilation stops

    ...
    ...
    ...

    procedure TMyForm.FormShow (Sender: TObject);
    var
        MySG: TCustomStringGrid;
    begin
        MySG := TCustomStringGrid.Create(self);
        MySG.Left := 100;
        MySG.Top := 40;
        MySG.Parent := self;
        MySG.SayHello();
    end;
```

The error I get:

```
File not found: 'TCustomStringGrid.dcu'
```

Please, help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is backwards. You would never instantiate a class named TCustomStringGrid. You would derive from it. If you want a data bound grid, deriving from TStringGrid feels wrong. I suspect you would be far better off using a ready made data bound grid. At the very least you need to brush up on component writing.

Comment: Why dont you want to read a component writers guide or something?

Comment: TCustomStringGrid is the user-given name of my derived class that I derive form the Delphi TStringGrid class. What's wrong with that? The thing is I don't actually want to have a data-bound grid in my application. I want to get data from the database, but I don't want it to be data-aware. I want to populate it by myself. This actually gives you a lot more flexibility over the grid than the standard Delphi data-aware components.

Comment: @MikhailRybkin: Because `TCustomStringGrid` is the name of an existing VCL class; it's the ancestor class for `TStringGrid` itself. (It's in the `Grids` unit.) Using the same name as a VCL base class is a poor idea both from a maintenance standpoint and from a component user's standpoint. (Actually, it makes no sense and probably won't compile, either: you have your `TCustomStringGrid` which inherits from `TStringGrid` which inherits from `TCustomStringGrid`. Think about it. <g>)

Comment: Well, I looked it up and it said that Lazarus had this component in its component library. But I couldn't find anything about the TCustomStringGrid in the Delphi help system though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is declared in `unit clsTCustomStringGrid;`, but your `uses` clause is using `TCustomStringGrid` (which is the class name).

Change your uses clause:

```
uses ...
  ...
  clsCustomStringGrid; 
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the uses clause add clsTCustomStringGrid, not TCustomStringGrid